# dynamically adding fields and content in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add fields dynamically to a web page so that a user can enter in additional amenities to a form.  By clicking on the add amenity button I can add the fields just fine.  However I cannot manage to get the values out of the input fields dynamically.  The objective is to display what they type after they leave the field (using `(':text').blur(myFunction);`).  This works for every other field I've used it on but for some reason I can't get the value to dynamically pull after I leave an 'amenity' field.

```
$('#new_amenity').on('click', function (event) {

  amenity++;
  $(this).prev().after('<br/><input type="text" value="" class="' + amenity + '" placeholder="Amenity" id="amenity" />');


  event.preventDefault();

});
```

Below is the code that I've tried to use to assign to the array.

```
//inside myfunction();
for(var i=1; $('#amenity').hasClass('.' + i);i++){
     amenities[i]=$('.'+i).val();   
}

//outside of function
$(":text").blur(myfunction);
```

Comment: Try jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: $('#amenity').hasClass('.' + i) returns true or false, how are you using it in your for loop??

Comment: `amenities[i].push($('.'+i).val());`  maybe?

Comment: I was under the impression that that is exactly what I am supposed to put in there.  As long as the conditional is true, do the loop, if false, don't.

Comment: How many elements have the sameID? why don't you just add a know class and loop over that? Also you may want to look into something like knockout which handles this stuff for you.

Comment: The number of elements that have the same id will be dynamic, so however many the user wants to add.  (class="' + amenity ) adds the class dynamically.  I'm trying to loop over the classes to get each value but it isn't assigning the values as I loop through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for dynamic elements.

```
$('body').on('change', 'input', myfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [hasClass function](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) only expects the name, it's not the same as the usual selector. It does not need the period in front.

```
for(var i=1; $('#amenity').hasClass(i);i++){
     amenities[i]=$('.'+i).val();   
}
```

Comment: I keep forgetting that as I'm used to doing the selectors for everything else.  Thanks.  This solved part of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fjCx7/3/ that may help you.

You have a lot going on here. first off you should not be putting the same ID on multiple things(bad practice)

your on blur event only gets bound on document load, you need something that will run dynamically.

> $('#container').on('blur', '.otherClass', myfunction);

instead of looping over the elements using a for loop, give it a known class before hand that way you can just do an each over them

> ```
> $('#container .otherClass').each(function(idx, item){
>     amenities.push($(item));
> });
> ```

Hopefully this will help you.

Also [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) is very good at doing stuff like this for you so you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: I know the id thing is bad practice and I'll have to find a better solution for that portion of the code.  I'm definitely gonna check out knockout as I'll be making tons of forms and any help is great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're running this on page load/document ready:

```
//outside of function
$(":text").blur(myfunction);
```

any new items you add aren't getting `myFunction` tied to the blur event - only the ones that existed on page load get the binding. Like the others said, you'll need to use event delegation or event bubbling.

**HTML**

```
<form id="amenities">
    <fieldset class="amenities">

    </fieldset>
    <button id="new_amenity">Add Amenity</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#new_amenity').on('click', function (event) {

    var count = $('.amenities').find('input').length;
    var amenity = '<br/><input type="text" value="" class="amenity-' + count + '" placeholder="Amenity" id="amenity" />';

    $('.amenities').append(amenity);

  event.preventDefault();

});

function myfunction(){
    //blah
}

$(".amenities").on('blur', 'input', myfunction);
```